# Trying to understand this lambda expression in scheme

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

Can you please help with this expression:

```
((lambda (a b) (* ***(b a)*** a)) 5 (lambda (c) (+ c (* 2 c))))
```

now I understand this expression = 75 and I understand that the first lambda takes to arguments a and b where a = 5 and b = (lambda (c) (+ c (* 2 c))) = 15 the only part of the expression i don't understand is the part I have put in bold and italics. In basic terms how will the expression read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This snippet:

```
(b a)
```

Expresses the fact that `b` is a function, and it's being applied to the `a` parameter. In particular, the value of `a` is `5`, and the value of `b` is the function:

```
(lambda (c) (+ c (* 2 c)))
```

So, replacing we obtain:

```
(* (b a) a)
(* ((lambda (c) (+ c (* 2 c))) 5) 5)
(* (+ 5 (* 2 5)) 5)
75
```